# where clause parentheses with comma separated values greater than

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, database-cursor

This is a very very noob and silly question but I can't seem to find what the following means in Postgres:

```
select * 
from table 
where (last_updated, id) > (timestamp with time zone '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00', 0)
```

Basically what does `(last_updated, id) > (timestamp with time zone '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00', 0)` mean ? what's it comparing ? changing second value doesn't seem to have effects on the results for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing tuples uses lexographical order, meaning that the second value is only used in case the first value ties.

So if your row has a timestamp of exactly that cutoff value, then the id needs to be greater than 0.

Hunch: This is used for cursor-based paging, where the second page starts off right after the last value on the first page (according to the sort criteria, here a timestamp), with id used as a tie-breaker (for when the last entry on the previous page and the first entry on the next page have the same sorting value --- probably unlikely for timestamps, but very likely if you order by salary or such).

Comment: yes you are right, this is being used for cursor based paging. thanks for the answer. Selecting this one as answer because of cursor guess in my case. Other answers are are correct though.

Answer (score 3):

It's comparing records together.

Record A is strictly greater than another B if the leftmost field of A is strictly greater than the leftmost field of B or, if they are equal, if the 2nd field of A is strictly greater than the 2nd field of B or, if those seconds fields are equal to each other to, if the 3rd field of A is strictly greater than the 3rd field of B or ... it can keep doing comparisons for more than 2 or 3 fields

Therefore, `(last_updated, id) > (timestamp with time zone '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00', 0)` is equivalent to:

1. Compare on the 1st field: `last_updated > '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00'`
2. if `last_updated = '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00'` then compare on the 2nd field `id > 0`

Or if I put it in a single boolean expression:

```
`last_updated > '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00'`
OR (
    last_updated = '2019-03-28 23:30:22.496+00:00'
    AND id > 0
)
```

As you can see, the other syntax was a lot shorter.

---

PS: In postgreSQL, at least version 11, you can use this kind of comparison for very nice lookup such as :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (field1, field2, field3) IN (SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM B)
```

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesized values are rows. From the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

> **4.2.13. Row Constructors**
>
> A row constructor is an expression that builds a row value (also called a composite value) using values for its member fields. A row constructor consists of the key word `ROW`, a left parenthesis, zero or more expressions (separated by commas) for the row field values, and finally a right parenthesis. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test');
> ```
>
> The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

And then a little further down:

> Also, it is possible to compare two row values or test a row with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL, for example:
>
> ```
> SELECT ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test') = ROW(1, 3, 'not the same');
>
> SELECT ROW(table.*) IS NULL FROM table;  -- detect all-null rows
> ```

So the two rows are compared element by element using `<`.